# How can I take the slopes of multiple time series contained within one matrix at the same time?

Tags: matlab

A is a 180x156 matrix and B is a 180x156 matrix. Within B are 180 vectors (corresponding to average temperatures at each latitude) that span through 156 time values (or months).

A is a series of time values (from time =1 to time = 156). I created A through repmat(1:time,180,1).

But plot(polyfit(A,B),1)*[1;0]) then doesn't output anything of substance.

Comment: What about a simple `diff(A)`?

Comment: I suppose you expect different polynomials to fit the data at different latitudes, or?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear that you want the coefficients of your line or if you want to plot the lines. If you just want to plot the lines we need to create some dummy data:

```
x = 1:156;
m = repmat((0:179)/179, 156, 1)';
A = repmat(x, 180, 1);
B = (m.*A)+randn(180, 156)+179*m;
```

The we need to plot it with symbols

```
plot(A', B', '*')
```

Then the `lsline` function can do its magic

```
lsline
```

You can see the source of `lsline` so you can create your own function that returns a matrix of coefficients instead of the handles to the plotted lines.